# Updating int on mySQL database from java

Tags: java, mysql

I'm having problem updating my sql server. The levels are normal keys and the idScore is the primary key. The levels are integers on the server. I have managed to get the levels but I've been stuck on updating to new values for a while. the "uCon" is working, it is logged onto the server. Doing other commands is posible. Must be the sql statement. the logged in acc is allowed to update and select. Can be changed ofc.

> ```
>         int highScore1 = 23;
>     int highScore2 = 6;
>     int highScore3 = 7;
>     String userName = "nisse";
>     try {
>         Statement st = Login.uCon.createStatement();
>         String sql = "UPDATE phantom.BoulderDash SET level1 = "+highScore1+", "
>                                                   + "level2 = "+highScore2+", "
>                                                   + "level3 = "+highScore3+","
>                                                   + "WHERE idScore = '" + userName + "';";
>         st.execute(sql);
>     } catch (Exception ex) {
>         System.out.println("fail");
>     }
> ```

Comment: So what's the problem? Are you getting an error?

Comment: " You have an error in your SQL syntax;" but I can't find what's wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a redundant comma (`,`) before your `where` clause - you should remove it:

```
String sql = "UPDATE phantom.BoulderDash SET level1 = "+highScore1+", "
                                                  + "level2 = "+highScore2+", "
                                                  + "level3 = "+highScore3+" " // No comma here
                                                  + "WHERE idScore = '" + userName + "';";
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the comma and make sure there's a space before the `WHERE`.

---

For debugging problems like this, consider adding a `System.out.println("sql="+sql);`

That way you can see the actual sql statement that is going to be submitted to the database.